# Kendo UI Grid - Filter Integer Column showing as decimal

Tags: user-interface, kendo-ui, grid

I am using the Kendo UI (2015.3.930) Grid Control and I have a integer textbox in a grid filter row that always as decimal when I apply the filter.

Here is my code:

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid((IEnumerable<UiController.Lot>)Model.Lots)
    .Name("Grid")
    .Columns(columns =>
    {
        columns.Bound(c => c.LotNumber).Title("Lot No")
            .Filterable(ftb =>ftb.ItemTemplate("NumericFilter"));
        columns.Bound(c => c.BranchName).Title("Branch Name");
    })
    .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "height: 530px;" })
    .Filterable(ftb => ftb.Mode(GridFilterMode.Row))
    .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
        .Server()
        .Model(model => { model.Id(p => p.Id); })
    )
)
```

My script section shows:

```
<script>
    function NumericFilter(args) {
        args.element.kendoNumericTextBox({
            "spinners": false,
            "format": "n0",
            "decimals": 0,
        });
    }
</script>
```

For an integer value of 10, it shows '10.00' after the applying the filter. Is there a way of showing the value without the decimal portion.

Answer (score 1):

I have prepared [Dojo example](http://dojo.telerik.com/afECe/5) just to show that it is possible.

I have not MVC wrappers but it looks, that it will work if you will do some small modifications to your code:

1] Change *ItemTemplate* in your Filterable to *UI*

```
columns.Bound(c => c.LotNumber).Title("Lot No").Filterable(ftb => ftb.UI("NumericFilter"));
```

2] Then you should be able to get wanted behaviour with syntax you showed in question with small (selector) modification

```
<script>
function NumericFilter(args) {
$(args).kendoNumericTextBox({
    "spinners" : false,
    "format": "n0",
    "decimals": 0,
});
}
```

Answer (score 1):

to customize this field, you need to use cell.template, please update your code as follow:

```
columns.Bound(c => c.LotNumber)
    .Title("Lot No")
    .Filterable(ftb => ftb.Cell(c => c.Template("NumericFilter")));
```

Comment: Great @Luis, please, mark this answer to help other users with this problem.

Comment: and it would be better to use format: "g" in your js function because when textbox loses the focus, it shows a number like 12,345.